# Adjust bokeh plot size in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm using bokeh to plot in a Jupyter Notebook, but I can't find a way to make the plot larger. I suspect it should be simple but I couldn't find a way to do this yet.

My code is (I'm using it to plot a dynamical system):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate

import biocircuits

import bokeh.io
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.plotting import figure

import panel as pn
pn.extension()

bokeh.io.output_notebook()

def dX_dt(X, Y, mu):
    return Y * ( mu - 2*X )


def dY_dt(X, Y, mu):
    return -mu*X + X**2 - Y**2 + 1

def ode_rhs(x, t, mu):
    """Compute right-hand-side of pair of ODEs."""
    X, Y = x
    return np.array(
        [
            dX_dt(X, Y, mu),
            dY_dt(X, Y, mu),
        ]
    )

# Specify parameters
mu = 3.0


# Package for the integrating function
params_X = (mu,)
params_Y = (mu,)

# Plotting the phase portrait
X_range = [-3, 3]
Y_range = [-3, 3]

p = figure(plot_height=1000, plot_width=1000)

p = biocircuits.phase_portrait(
    dX_dt,
    dY_dt,
    X_range,
    Y_range,
    params_X,
    params_Y,
    x_axis_label="X",
    y_axis_label="Y",
    color="#e6ab02",
    plot_width=1000,
    height=1000
)

if mu < 2:
  p.circle(*np.array([ mu/2 , np.sqrt(1 - (mu/2)**2) ]), color='black', size=10)
  p.circle(*np.array([ mu/2 , -np.sqrt(1 - (mu/2)**2) ]), color='white', line_color='black', line_width=2, size=10)

if mu > 2:
  p.circle(*np.array([ mu/2 + np.sqrt((mu/2)**2 - 1), 0 ]), color='black', size=10)
  p.circle(*np.array([ mu/2 - np.sqrt((mu/2)**2 - 1), 0 ]), color='white', line_color='black', line_width=2, size=10)

p.title.text = "Kd = 1, β₀ = 1"
bokeh.io.show(p)
```

Comment: `biocircuits.phase_portrait` is not part of Bokeh. Is seems that whatever it is, it is  ignoring your extra kwarg params. If it is returning a Bokeh `Plot` then try setting the width and height on the returned object (or inspecting them to see if they were set).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will be interested, I solved it using defining a bokeh figure type before calling the function and then pass it to the `biocircuits.phase_portrait` function:

```
p = figure(plot_height=550, plot_width=700, x_axis_label="X", y_axis_label="Y",
           title="μ = 3")

p = biocircuits.phase_portrait(
    dX_dt,
    dY_dt,
    X_range,
    Y_range,
    params_X,
    params_Y,
    x_axis_label="X",
    y_axis_label="Y",
    color="#e6ab02",
    p=p
)
```

This worked!